# Problem with wrapfigure when left positioning the figure

Tags: wrapfigure

I have the following piece of brief code. As you see, when I am using `verbatism` after the `wrapfigure` in the left mode {l}, the generated pdf file is a mess. But it is ok if I use `wrapfigure` with {r}. I appreciate any suggestion to solve the issue with the {l} mode. Thanks

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,onecolumn]{report}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{wrapfig}

\begin{document}

\begin{wrapfigure}[9]{l}{0.25\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=0.25\textwidth]{figs/Poly}
    \caption{Wrapfigure used to put this figure        here!!}\label{fig:right_fig}
\end{wrapfigure}
Finally, lets try multi-figure commands and see how it works. An example is shown in Fig.~\ref{fig:Multifigure} where we have a $2\times2$ image which  is inserted by the following code.
\begin{verbatim}
\begin{figure}
\begin{subfigure}{.5\textwidth}
  \centering
   \includegraphics[width=.9\linewidth]{figs/Poly}
   \caption{} \label{fig:Multifigure1}
\end{verbatim}

To plot data -- either save in a .txt file or some numbers -- using LaTeX, the "pgfplots" package should be added at the preamble. To import data from a .txt file, the "tikz" package should be added, too. The following is an example...
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a temporary solution:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,onecolumn]{report}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{wrapfig}

\begin{document}

\begin{wrapfigure}[5]{l}{0.25\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=0.25\textwidth]{Poly}
    \caption{Wrapfigure used to put this figure        here!!}\label{fig:right_fig}
\end{wrapfigure}

Finally, lets try multi-figure commands and see how it works. An example is shown in Fig.~\ref{fig:Multifigure} where we have a $2\times2$ image which  is inserted by the following code.

\hskip -7mm
\begin{minipage}{0.65\textwidth}
\begin{verbatim}
\begin{figure}
\begin{subfigure}{.5\textwidth}
  \centering
   \includegraphics[width=.9\linewidth]{figs/Poly}
   \caption{} \label{fig:Multifigure1}
\end{verbatim}
\end{minipage}

To plot data -- either save in a .txt file or some numbers -- using LaTeX, the "pgfplots" package should be added at the preamble. To import data from a .txt file, the "tikz" package should be added, too. The following is an example...
\end{document}
```

This is the output:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here's how to make the code fit line width, using the tools from `fancyvrb`to set the font size and the left margin, and package `geometry`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,onecolumn]{report}
\usepackage{geometry} 
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption, subcaption}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}

\begin{document}

\begin{wrapfigure}[9]{l}{0.25\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=0.25\textwidth]{figs/Poly}
    \caption{Wrapfigure used to put this figure here!!}\label{fig:right_fig}
\end{wrapfigure}
Finally, lets try multi-figure commands and see how it works. An example is shown in Fig.~\ref{fig:Multifigure} where we have a $2\times2$ image which is inserted by the following code.
\begin{Verbatim}[xleftmargin =-6pt, fontsize=\small]
\begin{figure}
\begin{subfigure}{.5\textwidth}
  \centering
   \includegraphics[width=.9\linewidth]{figs/Poly}
   \caption{} \label{fig:Multifigure1}
\end{Verbatim}

To plot data -- either save in a .txt file or some numbers -- using LaTeX, the "pgfplots" package should be added at the preamble. To import data from a .txt file, the "tikz" package should be added, too. The following is an example...

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are more satisfied with the output if you use `fancyvrb`'s  `Verbatim` environment instead. Nevertheless, keep in mind that the code is too wide and will either overlap with your image or flow into the margin:

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,onecolumn]{report}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}

\begin{document}

\begin{wrapfigure}[9]{l}{0.25\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=0.25\textwidth]{example-image}
    \caption{Wrapfigure used to put this figure        here!!}\label{fig:right_fig}
\end{wrapfigure}
Finally, lets try multi-figure commands and see how it works. An example is shown in Fig.~\ref{fig:Multifigure} where we have a $2\times2$ image which  is inserted by the following code.
\begin{Verbatim}
\begin{figure}
\begin{subfigure}{.5\textwidth}
  \centering
   \includegraphics[width=.9\linewidth]{figs/Poly}
   \caption{} \label{fig:Multifigure1}
\end{Verbatim}

To plot data -- either save in a .txt file or some numbers -- using LaTeX, the "pgfplots" package should be added at the preamble. To import data from a .txt file, the "tikz" package should be added, too. The following is an example...
\end{document}
```